# Set name for events of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using an internal framework that uses custom-made component that fire their own events. That framework also has an event listener that listens to all those events using topic/subscriber pattern, the topic being the name of the event triggered.

I am using several html  in my page, and need to be able to listen to each 'change' event for each select separately. For example,

```
<select id="first" nativeId="firstNative">
    <option>TEST</option>
    <option>TEST2</option>
</select>
<select id="second" nativeId="secondNative">
    <option>TEST3</option>
    <option>TEST4</option>
<select>
```

and when there is a 'change' event made for the first select, I need to do something. If the second  has a 'change' event, another thing happens.

How can I give a custom name to each select's change event so that I can register it in the framework and it's not confused with other events?

EDIT: The question is more javascript/jquery oriented. I do not need to change the framework or how it works (it's internal and I cannot share it). I'm interested in seeing how can I change an element's default event name. Both the first and second  throw a "change" event, and I cannot just listen to the "change" event because I cannot tell which element fired it. I would like for the selects to throw a specifically-named event instead of the generic "change".

Comment: what framework? Where's the link to the docs for it? We can't guess what *"I need the framework to do something"* entails. Also presumably you can listen to the framework events

Comment: I'm interested in seeing how can I set a custom name for the select's onchange event so I can have more granular event handling. Right now, both select's fire up a "change" event regardless of if it was the first or the second <select>. 

The framework is internal to my company and I cannot grant access to it, and I cannot change it either.

Comment: so wouldn't getting the id or the `nativeId` help inside the event handler?

Comment: I've tried "second.change" and "secondNative.change" but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Event creating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

You can change `change` event to other custom event.

1. Create custom event.
2. Add custom event handler.
3. Dispatch custom event when you need it.

```js
var selectOneEvent = new Event('select.one.change');
var selectTwoEvent = new Event('select.two.change');

document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('change', function(){
    this.dispatchEvent(selectOneEvent);
});


document.getElementById('second').addEventListener('change', function(){
    this.dispatchEvent(selectTwoEvent);
});

document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('select.one.change', function(){
    alert('select.one.change');
});

document.getElementById('second').addEventListener('select.two.change', function(){
    alert('select.two.change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="first" nativeId="firstNative">
    <option>TEST</option>
    <option>TEST2</option>
</select>
<select id="second" nativeId="secondNative">
    <option>TEST3</option>
    <option>TEST4</option>
<select>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot just listen to the "change" event because I cannot tell which element fired it

**Sure you can.**

---

Inside an event handler `this` is the element the event occured on and thus you can use things like `this.id` or `$(this).attr('nativeId')` or  `this.getAttribute('nativeId')` as identifiers for the specific element

```js
$('select').on('change', function(){
    console.log('id =',this.id);
    console.log('nativeId =',$(this).attr('nativeId'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="first" nativeId="firstNative">
    <option>TEST</option>
    <option>TEST2</option>
</select>
<select id="second" nativeId="secondNative">
    <option>TEST3</option>
    <option>TEST4</option>
<select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example, how you can dynamically `addEventListener` to a DOM element. Perhaps you might find use in that.

```js
function test() {
  console.log('test');
}

function test1() {
  console.log('test1');
}

var selectors = [
  { id: 'first', eventType: 'change', cb: test },
  { id: 'second', eventType: 'change', cb: test1 }
];


//pure JS way
for (i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++) {
  var sel = selectors[i];
  document.getElementById(sel.id).addEventListener( sel.eventType, sel.cb); 
}

// ES6 way
//selectors.forEach(sel => document.getElementById(sel.id).addEventListener( sel.eventType, sel.cb )
//);
```

```html
<select id="first" nativeId="firstNative">
    <option>TEST</option>
    <option>TEST2</option>
</select>
<select id="second" nativeId="secondNative">
    <option>TEST3</option>
    <option>TEST4</option>
<select>
```